# Showing $\left(\sum_1^\infty 2^{-n} \mathbf{1}_{x\in(0,1)}(x-r_n)^{-1/2}\right)^2$ is not integrable

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

A small part to a homework problem.

> Let $\{r_n\}_1^\infty$ be an enumeration of the rationals, and let $f(x) = x^{-1/2}$ if $0<x<1$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. Define $g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} f(x-r_n)$. Show that $g^2$ is not integrable on any interval.

I have shown that $g \in L^1$, which follows by using the comparison test on the series and noting that $f(x-r_n) \le 2$, noting that each term in the series is in $L^1$, and applying a few standard theorems about swapping sums and integral signs.

I have shown that $g < \infty$ a.e., which follows more or less directly from the definition.

Using $g^2 = g\cdot g$, I have shown that $g^2 < \infty$ a.e. So this rules out using that $g^2 = \infty$ on sets of non-zero Lebesgue measure. It would suffice to show that $g^2 \notin L^1$, but I have a limited arsenal of tools that state that a function is *not* $L^1$. I am loath to write the product of the series as a Cauchy sum. Is there some other way?

Comment: Hint: Every interval contains some $r_n$ and $g^2(x)\geqslant4^{-n}|x-r_n|\mathbf 1_{0\lt x\lt1}$, where the RHS is not integrable.

Comment: @Did Thanks, I thought it might be something like that. I will need to figure out how to come up with that inequality, I don't see it right away but I will think a bit on it :)

Comment: Every sum of nonnegative terms is at least equal to each of the terms. Nothing more fancy is needed.

Comment: @Did I guess I'm just curious how you got the $(x-r_n)^{-1/2}$ to become an absolute value, and not a "one-over" the absolute value.

Comment: Typo, actually, $g^2(x)\geqslant4^{-n}(x-r_n)^{-1}$ on some interval $(r_n,r_n+\varepsilon)\subset(0,1)$.

Comment: @Did thanks, I determined it had to be such after some thought. Much appreciated :)

Comment: @Emily Can you please tell me from where you got $f(x-r_n)\le 2$ ?

Comment: @S717717 Sure; $f(x) = 0$ if $x \le 0$ or $x \ge 1$; that means values of $r_n$ where $f(x)$ is non-zero must be in $(-1,1)$. Taking $r_n = -1$, we get supremum of the domain of $x - r_n$, which gives us $f(2)$. Then recognize that $\sqrt2 < 2$.

Comment: @Emily Sorry.! I'm not getting.. You have written that " that values of $r_n$ where $f(x)$ is non-zero must be in $(-1,1)$. " How it is ? As for $x\le 0$ ,  $f(x)=0$. I think " values of $r_n$ where $f(x)$ is non-zero must be in $(0,1)$. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments in the question:

It is clear that every interval contains some $r_n$, and that the Cauchy sum contains a term like $4^{-1}\frac{1}{|x-r_n|}$. Therefore, on any interval $g^2 \ge \frac{4^{-n}}{|x-r_n|}$, and the right-hand side is not integrable.